# WPF: Updating private setter variable IS not raising propertyChanged event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My View model has the following code. I'm using MVVMLIght

```
class SettingsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SettingsViewModel()
    { }

    string _customerName;

    public string customerName
    {
        get
        {
            return _customerName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_customerName == value)
                return;
            _customerName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("customerName");
        }
    }

    private void _changeNamePrivate()
    {
        this._customerName = "SomePrivateName";
    }

    private void _changeNamePublic()
    {
        this.customerName = "SomePublicName";
    }
}
```

My question is when I call `_changeNamePrivate` the `RaisePropertyChanged` event handler is not raised. But it's raised only  when I call  `_changeNamePublic` function. Shouldn't updating the private variable raise the property changed event ?

Comment: No it shouldn't. You only do `RaisePropertyChanged` in the setter of `customerName`, which also changes `_customerName`. When you change `_customerName` directly you just change private field

Comment: The behaviour you describe is expected, when you set `_customerName` you are simply changing the backing field, you are not calling the setter of property `customerName` so the `RaisePropertyChanged` event does not get called.

Comment: Wow.  That's like asking why turning on the lightswitch in the bathroom doesn't turn the light on in the kitchen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dkozl and @Ben already said, this is expected:

The code you provided, will only call `RaisePropertyChanged` event handler in the set section of the `customerName` property:

```
public string customerName
{
    get
    {
        return _customerName;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_customerName == value)
            return;
        _customerName = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("customerName");
    }
}
```

As such, in your `_changeNamePublic()` it changes the value of the property so that it will call the set section and raise the `RaisePropertyChanged` handler. Where as in your `_changeNamePrivate()`, it only assign value to the field `_customerName`.

Answer (score 1):

`_customerName` is a field, not a property. When you assign something to it, it writes directly to the storage location, it doesn't execute any other code. On the other hand, `customerName` is a property: when you assign something to it, it executes the property setter, which raises the event.